# Getting leaf values from any kind of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to get all leaf value of any kind object as array.
Here is sample object and I want to get [1, 2, 3] from this object.

```
     {
    “group1”:[
        {
            “value1”:”1”,
            "value2”:”2”
        },
        {
           “gropu2”:[{
            "gropu3”:”3”
              }]
        }]
 }
```

Here is current implementation.

```
 var t = {
    "a":[
        {
            "a":"1",
            "b":"2"
        },
        {
           "d":[{
            "e":"3"
           }]
        }]
 }
 function getNode( node ){
    if(node == null)
        return null;
    if(typeof node !== 'object'){
        return [node];
    }
    var arr = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < node.length ; i ++){
        Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, getNode(node[i]));
    }
    return arr;
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(getNode(t));
 });
```

But it is showing nothing.
I can’t understand where I am doing wrong with my implementation and is there any other easy way to get this done?

Comment: What is uclid? Ευκλείδης maybe? ;)

Comment: Not a code issue rather a Math problem

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use the Chrome Developer Tools. This has a debugger which allows you to step through your code to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line.

```
for( var i = 0; i < node.length ; i ++){
```

Here you can not access all element of `object` using `for` loop.
You have to convert `object` to `array` and then do that.

```
var array_node = Object.keys(node).map(function(key) { return node[key] });
for( var i = 0; i < array_node.length ; i ++){
    Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, getNode(array_node[i]));
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8jLLjenj/)

Comment: Thanks it's working, but is there any other easy way, like object built-in function?